# translate aggregate SQL query with case and When to MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have executed with no problem the query in SQL but it does not work in Access
Case is not avaliable in Access right, so IIf must be used...

```
select
    sum(case when date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01' then value else 0 end) as sum1,
    sum(case when date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01' then value else 0 end) as sum2,
    sum(case when situation like 'Urgent' then 1 else 0 end) as urgent,
    sum(case when situation like 'Anual' then 1 else 0 end) as anual,
    sum(1) as total
from mytable
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
Will this query work?

```
  select
        sum(IIf date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01',value,0) as sum1,
        sum(IIf date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01',value,0) as sum2,
        sum(IIf situation like 'Urgent',1,0 ) as urgent,
        sum(IIf situation like 'Anual' ,1,0 ) as anual,
        sum(1) as total
    from mytable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses for `IIf()` as in `IIf(expression, truepart, falsepart)`

Enclose `date` and `value` in square brackets because both are reserved words.

Your `Like` comparisons didn't include any pattern matching, so I substituted `=` instead.

I assumed date is Date/Time data type, so enclosed the values with the `#` delimiter.

```
SELECT
    Sum(IIf([date] BETWEEN #2012-05-01# AND #2012-06-01#,[value],0)) AS Sum1,
    Sum(IIf([date] BETWEEN #2012-05-01# AND #2012-10-01#,[value],0)) AS Sum2,
    Sum(IIf(situation = 'Urgent',1,0 )) AS urgent,
    Sum(IIf(situation = 'Anual' ,1,0 )) AS anual,
    Sum(1) AS total
FROM mytable;
```